# align major grid line to the end of bar width instead of cutting into bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi suppose I have a bar plot with blue grid lines like shown below. What I want is for the blue line to not cut into the bar plot but only start after the whole width ends.  Is this possible?

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) + geom_bar(aes(weight = displ)) + 
    theme(panel.grid.major.x  = element_line(colour="blue", size=0.5))
```

the figure's arrows show where I want the grid line align and not cut into the bar. 
[image: gg]

Answer (score 1):

Would you settle for using `geom_vline`?

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) + geom_bar(aes(weight = displ)) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept= seq_along(unique(mpg$class)) + 0.45, color = "blue") +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

The other option might be to use `position_nudge`, but then you have to worry about `axis.text.x` position and padding the x limit.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = class)) + geom_bar(aes(weight = displ), position = position_nudge(-0.45)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.1,0.4)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x  = element_line(colour="blue", size=0.5),
        axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: My take was the same, except that I would add `+ theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())` to get rid of the x axis grid.

Comment: @Ian Campbell hmm that is a good idea. I wonder if there is  a way to avoid hardcoding the xintercept?  that way this can be apply easily to other plots?

Comment: Sure, I edited my answer with a possible way to avoid hardcoding.